# Ionic Android Build Failing

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build this application (I have successfully built the iOS version)

When I run ionic cordova build android I get following output

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
        > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
           > Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+ as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads are available.
             Searched in the following locations:
                 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
                 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
                 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
                 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
                 https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
                 https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
                 file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
                 file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
             Required by:
                 :android:unspecified

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

        BUILD FAILED

        Total time: 19.489 secs
        Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
        > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
           > Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+ as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads are available.
             Searched in the following locations:
                 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
                 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
                 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
                 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
                 https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
                 https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
                 file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/maven-metadata.xml
                 file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/
             Required by:
                 :android:unspecified

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: `play-services-ads:+`... Never use a plus as a version unless you want the code to break

Answer (score 0):

Open your Android SDK Manager. Verify if you have installed: Android Support Repository, Google Play Services and Google Repository (as shown in image below). If not, install it.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Comment: All installed. Still not working. Can you please help me with it.